# Nested queries with ANDs and ORs in TYPO3/Extbase

Tags: typo3, extbase, subquery

I need to build some complicated queries for a TYPO3 extension. One of these queries is looking for a custom entry in the set of a given user or in the set of the default entries. The default entries are saved with `cruser_id = 0`. Therefor it's necessary to build nested logical operators.

I tried it as follows:

```
public function findById($cId, $userId) {
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setEnableFieldsToBeIgnored(['pid', 'cruser_id', 'sys_language_uid']);

    $res = $query->matching(
        $query->logicalAnd(
            $query->equals("id", $cId),
            $query->logicalOr(
                $query->equals("cruser_id", $userId), //include custom entries
                $query->equals("cruser_id", 0) //also include default entries
            )
    ))->execute()->getFirst();
    print_r($res);
```

And that doesn't work :-( I tried to debug, but I found no indication for an error in my code. It would be great, if someone can help me here.

Comment: For me your constraints look ok, except `setEnableFieldsToBeIgnored(['pid', 'cruser_id', 'sys_language_uid'])` - these are not enable-fields. Did you check a query, that is built?

Comment: I spent a lot of time in SQL query debugging, but I found my issue. Before building the constraints I should have done  `$query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(false);` in order to ignore the `pid`. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up the comments:

If your records are located not in configured persistence-pid `plugin.tx_yourext.persistence.storagePid`, or you don't have a persistence storage configured at all, then you need to disable pid-checks.

`setEnableFieldsToBeIgnored` can apply only to so-called *enable-fields*, which in most cases are **disabled, endtime, fe_group, starttime** and configured via `$GLOBALS['TCA'][$table]['ctrl']['enablecolumns']`.

To suppress *pid*-check, you should use `setRespectStoragePage(false)`. For *sys_language* there is a `setRespectSysLanguage(false)`. And *cruser_id* is not checked at all, so you can skip it.